# KNN: TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, knn

I'm using KNN code from ([sklearn.org](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html#sphx-glr-download-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-classification-py)) with my own data.  (I'm not using the Iris dataset.) I've cut the data way down for this post so I can include both arrays here.

```
working_df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 475 entries, 236582 to 237060
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Salinity                  475 non-null float64
Temperature               475 non-null float64
Calculated Chlorophyll    475 non-null float64
Station_group             475 non-null object
```

I get X and y from the Dataframe (printout of X and y below):

```
X = np.array(working_df[['Salinity', 'Temperature']]) 
y = np.array(working_df['Station_group'])
```

I'm getting errors from the KNN code:

```
ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range
```

(from the call to `plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)`)

and

```
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

(from the call to `plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold, edgecolor='k', s=20)`)

I swear this worked (briefly) earlier today. I don't even see where it's "iterating".

This is the code I'm using (I didn't write it)

```
n_neighbors = 3

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# Create color maps
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['orange', 'cyan', 'cornflowerblue'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['darkorange', 'c', 'darkblue'])

for weights in ['uniform', 'distance']:
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights=weights)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

    # Plot also the training points
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold,
                edgecolor='k', s=20)
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    plt.title("3-Class classification (k = %i, weights = '%s')"
              % (n_neighbors, weights))

plt.show()
```

X:

```
array([[16.7 , 20.88],
       [16.  , 21.22],
       [16.7 , 20.87],
       [15.87, 21.22],
       [16.29, 21.1 ],
       [16.6 , 20.94],
       [15.92, 21.23],
       [17.1 , 21.  ],
       [17.3 , 20.91],
       [17.09, 20.99],
       [17.48, 20.86],
       [17.23, 20.95],
       [17.36, 20.88],
       [17.09, 21.  ],
       [17.29, 20.92],
       [17.08, 21.  ],
       [17.42, 20.87],
       [17.77, 20.69],
       [18.13, 20.5 ],
       [17.59, 20.83],
       [17.88, 20.62],
       [18.17, 20.48],
       [17.68, 20.75],
       [18.07, 20.53],
       [17.59, 20.83],
       [18.13, 20.49],
       [18.19, 20.78],
       [18.46, 20.7 ],
       [18.29, 20.76],
       [18.41, 20.72],
       [18.23, 20.78],
       [18.35, 20.75],
       [17.88, 20.7 ],
       [18.44, 20.71],
       [18.25, 20.77],
       [18.38, 20.73],
       [18.26, 20.53],
       [19.21, 20.12],
       [18.78, 20.46],
       [19.14, 20.18],
       [18.61, 20.52],
       [18.84, 20.42],
       [19.18, 20.14],
       [18.68, 20.52],
       [18.99, 20.3 ],
       [19.65, 19.83],
       [19.85, 19.65],
       [19.73, 19.76],
       [19.59, 19.87],
       [19.79, 19.71],
       [19.71, 19.78],
       [19.86, 19.63],
       [19.75, 19.75],
       [19.62, 19.84],
       [19.82, 19.67],
       [19.72, 19.77],
       [19.58, 19.89],
       [19.77, 19.72],
       [19.9 , 19.59],
       [20.1 , 19.38],
       [19.96, 19.53],
       [19.89, 19.62],
       [20.1 , 19.37],
       [19.92, 19.57],
       [20.  , 19.49],
       [19.9 , 19.61],
       [20.11, 19.36],
       [19.94, 19.55],
       [19.89, 19.63],
       [20.07, 19.41],
       [20.11, 19.39],
       [20.18, 19.29],
       [20.14, 19.33],
       [20.16, 19.3 ],
       [20.12, 19.36],
       [20.18, 19.29],
       [20.15, 19.32],
       [20.18, 19.29],
       [20.13, 19.34],
       [20.16, 19.31],
       [20.58, 19.02],
       [20.58, 19.01],
       [20.6 , 19.  ],
       [20.58, 19.02],
       [20.59, 19.01],
       [20.56, 19.04],
       [20.61, 18.99],
       [20.58, 19.01],
       [20.6 , 19.  ],
       [21.14, 18.75],
       [21.22, 18.63],
       [21.27, 18.59],
       [21.14, 18.73],
       [21.24, 18.61],
       [21.18, 18.67],
       [21.25, 18.6 ],
       [21.87, 18.1 ],
       [21.91, 18.03],
       [21.8 , 18.29],
       [21.92, 18.01],
       [21.89, 18.06],
       [21.91, 18.02],
       [21.84, 18.17],
       [21.9 , 18.04],
       [21.92, 18.01],
       [22.15, 17.79],
       [22.31, 17.6 ],
       [22.22, 17.75],
       [21.99, 17.99],
       [22.3 , 17.62],
       [22.19, 17.77],
       [22.32, 17.6 ],
       [21.89, 18.24],
       [22.22, 17.76],
       [22.07, 17.88],
       [22.31, 17.62],
       [22.24, 17.74],
       [21.93, 18.11],
       [22.29, 17.65],
       [22.1 , 18.22],
       [23.24, 16.8 ],
       [22.73, 17.34],
       [23.51, 16.49],
       [22.17, 18.11],
       [23.08, 16.98],
       [23.62, 16.35],
       [22.32, 17.86],
       [23.33, 16.69],
       [22.89, 17.17],
       [23.57, 16.41],
       [22.11, 18.21],
       [23.16, 16.89],
       [23.62, 16.35],
       [22.52, 17.56],
       [23.45, 16.56],
       [22.99, 17.07],
       [23.6 , 16.38],
       [22.87, 17.34],
       [23.43, 16.85],
       [23.27, 16.94],
       [23.71, 16.55],
       [23.32, 16.92],
       [24.11, 16.36],
       [23.04, 17.14],
       [23.57, 16.74],
       [23.31, 16.92],
       [23.86, 16.41],
       [22.61, 17.66],
       [23.35, 16.9 ],
       [24.2 , 16.33],
       [23.18, 17.  ],
       [23.68, 16.65],
       [23.32, 16.92],
       [23.98, 16.4 ],
       [22.08, 15.89],
       [23.61, 16.02],
       [24.33, 15.94],
       [22.82, 16.  ],
       [23.9 , 16.  ],
       [24.34, 15.93],
       [21.8 , 15.95],
       [23.39, 16.04],
       [24.29, 15.96],
       [24.63, 15.79],
       [22.58, 15.9 ],
       [23.67, 16.01],
       [24.34, 15.93],
       [21.86, 15.93],
       [22.98, 16.08],
       [24.09, 15.98],
       [24.36, 15.91],
       [21.87, 15.93],
       [23.48, 16.03],
       [24.32, 15.95],
       [22.71, 15.96],
       [23.73, 16.01],
       [24.35, 15.92],
       [21.81, 15.95],
       [23.15, 16.08],
       [24.22, 15.96],
       [24.36, 15.92],
       [24.12, 15.3 ],
       [24.71, 15.08],
       [25.11, 14.96],
       [26.25, 14.6 ],
       [26.36, 14.56],
       [23.57, 15.56],
       [24.23, 15.26],
       [24.93, 15.01],
       [25.51, 14.83],
       [26.23, 14.6 ],
       [26.42, 14.54],
       [23.79, 15.44],
       [24.56, 15.13],
       [25.06, 14.97],
       [26.07, 14.65],
       [26.31, 14.57],
       [24.17, 15.28],
       [24.84, 15.04],
       [25.29, 14.9 ],
       [26.24, 14.6 ],
       [26.41, 14.54],
       [23.69, 15.5 ],
       [24.28, 15.24],
       [24.97, 15.  ],
       [25.57, 14.81],
       [26.21, 14.61],
       [26.43, 14.53],
       [23.86, 15.41],
       [24.6 , 15.12],
       [25.07, 14.98],
       [26.02, 14.67],
       [26.33, 14.57],
       [24.19, 15.27],
       [24.89, 15.02],
       [25.48, 14.84],
       [26.23, 14.6 ],
       [26.48, 14.52],
       [23.77, 15.46],
       [24.37, 15.2 ],
       [25.03, 14.98],
       [25.86, 14.72],
       [26.33, 14.57],
       [16.07, 17.03],
       [22.22, 15.72],
       [19.57, 16.38],
       [21.59, 15.88],
       [17.38, 16.82],
       [22.57, 15.62],
       [19.71, 16.34],
       [15.6 , 17.15],
       [21.84, 15.82],
       [18.69, 16.57],
       [22.67, 15.6 ],
       [20.64, 16.12],
       [14.96, 17.07],
       [16.85, 16.72],
       [13.66, 17.49],
       [18.33, 16.51],
       [15.36, 16.99],
       [17.69, 16.59],
       [14.44, 17.19],
       [16.06, 16.85],
       [12.9 , 18.12],
       [18.04, 16.53],
       [13.52, 17.37],
       [17.95, 16.54],
       [12.19, 17.92],
       [15.43, 16.99],
       [18.95, 16.4 ],
       [12.72, 17.93],
       [17.06, 16.7 ],
       [19.53, 16.29],
       [11.86, 18.11],
       [13.84, 17.26],
       [18.85, 16.4 ],
       [12.23, 18.  ],
       [16.33, 16.83],
       [18.98, 16.4 ],
       [13.11, 17.63],
       [17.24, 16.66],
       [19.96, 16.2 ],
       [12.07, 17.85],
       [14.68, 17.12],
       [18.94, 16.39],
       [12.35, 18.09],
       [16.66, 16.77],
       [19.15, 16.36],
       [13.59, 17.28],
       [16.67, 16.78],
       [11.92, 17.61],
       [15.39, 17.  ],
       [12.51, 17.47],
       [16.  , 16.91],
       [14.16, 17.18],
       [11.93, 17.6 ],
       [15.88, 16.93],
       [12.87, 17.4 ],
       [16.29, 16.85],
       [11.86, 17.67],
       [14.62, 17.11],
       [12.15, 17.55],
       [15.9 , 16.93],
       [10.54, 17.7 ],
       [ 9.53, 17.85],
       [ 9.29, 18.04],
       [10.2 , 17.74],
       [ 9.4 , 17.92],
       [ 5.33, 18.14],
       [ 4.31, 18.59],
       [ 5.91, 18.06],
       [ 4.97, 18.23],
       [ 5.54, 18.11],
       [ 4.55, 18.39],
       [ 5.13, 18.19],
       [ 5.79, 18.08],
       [ 4.78, 18.29],
       [ 3.  , 18.37],
       [ 3.57, 18.3 ],
       [ 4.63, 18.2 ],
       [ 3.4 , 18.32],
       [ 4.41, 18.22],
       [ 2.69, 18.42],
       [ 3.48, 18.31],
       [ 4.54, 18.21],
       [ 3.21, 18.34],
       [ 3.9 , 18.27],
       [ 3.43, 18.32],
       [ 4.47, 18.22],
       [ 2.87, 18.39],
       [ 3.51, 18.31],
       [ 4.57, 18.21],
       [ 3.37, 18.32],
       [ 4.22, 18.24],
       [ 2.43, 18.47],
       [ 3.46, 18.31],
       [ 4.52, 18.22],
       [ 0.64, 18.89],
       [ 0.77, 18.83],
       [ 0.87, 18.79],
       [ 0.67, 18.88],
       [ 0.53, 19.14],
       [ 0.74, 18.84],
       [ 0.64, 18.89],
       [ 0.8 , 18.82],
       [ 0.91, 18.78],
       [ 0.69, 18.86],
       [ 0.61, 18.9 ],
       [ 0.75, 18.84],
       [ 0.65, 18.88],
       [ 0.84, 18.8 ],
       [ 0.98, 18.75],
       [ 0.5 , 19.28],
       [ 0.72, 18.85],
       [ 0.33, 19.05],
       [ 0.36, 19.01],
       [ 0.36, 19.  ],
       [ 0.35, 19.  ],
       [ 0.35, 19.01],
       [ 0.36, 19.01],
       [ 0.31, 19.19],
       [ 0.35, 19.01],
       [ 0.36, 19.01],
       [ 0.38, 19.03],
       [ 0.35, 19.01],
       [ 0.36, 19.01],
       [ 0.36, 19.  ],
       [ 0.36, 19.  ],
       [ 0.36, 19.01],
       [ 0.37, 19.02],
       [ 0.32, 19.1 ],
       [ 0.36, 19.01],
       [ 0.36, 19.  ],
       [ 0.39, 19.03],
       [ 0.35, 19.01],
       [ 0.36, 19.01],
       [ 0.36, 19.01],
       [ 0.36, 19.  ],
       [ 0.36, 19.01],
       [ 0.38, 19.03],
       [ 0.16, 19.25],
       [ 0.16, 19.31],
       [ 0.18, 19.22],
       [ 0.16, 19.26],
       [ 0.21, 19.13],
       [ 0.16, 19.34],
       [ 0.16, 19.24],
       [ 0.16, 19.3 ],
       [ 0.21, 19.16],
       [ 0.16, 19.25],
       [ 0.22, 19.13],
       [ 0.16, 19.31],
       [ 0.17, 19.24],
       [ 0.16, 19.27],
       [ 0.21, 19.14],
       [ 0.07, 19.48],
       [ 0.07, 19.47],
       [ 0.07, 19.48],
       [ 0.07, 19.5 ],
       [ 0.07, 19.48],
       [ 0.07, 19.48],
       [ 0.07, 19.47],
       [ 0.07, 19.94],
       [ 0.07, 19.48],
       [ 0.07, 19.5 ],
       [ 0.07, 19.47],
       [ 0.07, 19.48],
       [ 0.07, 19.47],
       [ 0.07, 19.52],
       [ 0.07, 19.48],
       [ 0.07, 19.45],
       [ 0.07, 19.44],
       [ 0.07, 19.58],
       [ 0.07, 19.44],
       [ 0.07, 19.82],
       [ 0.07, 19.43],
       [ 0.07, 19.47],
       [ 0.07, 19.43],
       [ 0.07, 19.73],
       [ 0.07, 19.42],
       [ 0.07, 19.63],
       [ 0.07, 19.62],
       [ 0.07, 19.63],
       [ 0.07, 19.61],
       [ 0.07, 19.62],
       [ 0.07, 19.98],
       [ 0.07, 19.62],
       [ 0.07, 19.63],
       [ 0.07, 19.62],
       [ 0.07, 19.78],
       [ 0.07, 19.62],
       [ 0.07, 19.92],
       [ 0.07, 19.69],
       [ 0.07, 19.81],
       [ 0.07, 19.69],
       [ 0.07, 20.1 ],
       [ 0.07, 19.7 ],
       [ 0.07, 19.68],
       [ 0.07, 19.86],
       [ 0.07, 19.69],
       [ 0.07, 19.76],
       [ 0.07, 19.69],
       [ 0.07, 20.07],
       [ 0.07, 19.7 ],
       [ 0.07, 19.82],
       [ 0.07, 19.68],
       [ 0.07, 19.71],
       [ 0.07, 19.68],
       [ 0.06, 19.64],
       [ 0.07, 20.24],
       [ 0.06, 19.63],
       [ 0.06, 19.7 ],
       [ 0.06, 19.62],
       [ 0.06, 19.63],
       [ 0.06, 19.89],
       [ 0.06, 19.63],
       [ 0.06, 19.68],
       [ 0.06, 19.62],
       [ 0.07, 20.55],
       [ 0.06, 19.63],
       [ 0.06, 19.8 ],
       [ 0.06, 19.62],
       [ 0.06, 19.81],
       [ 0.07, 20.3 ],
       [ 0.06, 19.82],
       [ 0.06, 19.91],
       [ 0.07, 20.8 ],
       [ 0.06, 19.81],
       [ 0.07, 20.22],
       [ 0.06, 19.85],
       [ 0.07, 20.39],
       [ 0.06, 19.82],
       [ 0.06, 19.99],
       [ 0.06, 19.22],
       [ 0.06, 19.89],
       [ 0.06, 19.18],
       [ 0.06, 19.49],
       [ 0.06, 19.22],
       [ 0.06, 19.8 ],
       [ 0.06, 19.18],
       [ 0.06, 19.33],
       [ 0.06, 19.93],
       [ 0.06, 19.2 ],
       [ 0.06, 19.57],
       [ 0.06, 19.18],
       [ 0.08, 19.86],
       [ 0.08, 19.53],
       [ 0.08, 19.56],
       [ 0.08, 19.55],
       [ 0.08, 19.74],
       [ 0.08, 19.5 ],
       [ 0.08, 19.56],
       [ 0.08, 19.54],
       [ 0.08, 19.57],
       [ 0.08, 19.55]])
```

y:

```
array(['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
       '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
       '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
       '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
       '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
       '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
       '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
       '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
       '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
       '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
       '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
       '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
       '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
       '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
       '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
       '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
       '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
       '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4',
       '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4',
       '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4',
       '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4',
       '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4',
       '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4',
       '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
       '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6',
       '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6'], dtype=object)
```

the traceback:

[image: Traceback part 2]

[image: Traceback part 2]

[image: Traceback part 2]

Comment: your error occurs when you are plotting the data: `plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold, edgecolor='k', s=20)`

Comment: Um, yes? I know where the error is. I don't know why.

Comment: I was simply pointing out that there are two errors: a value error for `c=y` when you are calling the scatter plot and a type error.

Comment: The type error occurs at `plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)` I am not familiar with `pcolormesh` so I cannot help.

Comment: @Chris - sorry; I misunderstood. And thanks for noting the value error is for c=y (it could have been anywhere in that call).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cmaps only have 3 colors in them, but there are 6 classes that each need a color assigned to them. Try listing 6 colors in the ListedColormaps rather than 3.